# Jupyter notebook does not connect to kernel(2) - conda + mc os 11.5 + appnope

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I work on mac os 11.5!

I created a virtual environment with conda and activated it:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6

conda activate myenv
```

I tried to install jupyter notebook in this new environment:

```
conda install jupyter notebook
```

It went well! Now that I launch it, it tries to connect to kernel for 1 min, does not succeed and returns error!

The error I get (I just copy the last lines as Stackoverflow doesn't let me post too much code ):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
  File "~/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 60, in beginActivityWithOptions
    NSProcessInfo = C('NSProcessInfo')
  File "~/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 38, in C
    assert ret is not None, "Couldn't find Class %s" % classname
AssertionError: Couldn't find Class NSProcessInfo
[W 16:03:16.833 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 16:03:16.834 NotebookApp] Kernel 23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942 died, removing from map.
[W 16:04:01.865 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942
[E 16:04:01.868 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942)
[W 16:04:02.892 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942/channels?session_id=fef577101b6a43d781a438c90d50d561 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942
[W 16:04:02.905 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942/channels?session_id=fef577101b6a43d781a438c90d50d561 (::1) 15.490000ms referer=None
[W 16:04:04.917 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 23590965-8381-42a0-ab03-f81495576942:fef577101b6a43d781a438c90d50d561
[I 16:05:04.070 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
^C[I 16:05:18.396 NotebookApp] interrupted
Serving notebooks from local directory: ~
0 active kernels
Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 is running at:
http://localhost:8888/?token=e5f60b72b0219930db87cfda37664107b266da3fe505bc17
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=e5f60b72b0219930db87cfda37664107b266da3fe505bc17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to be an `appnope` specific issue, try to reduce with only installing appnope and importing it from python shell.

Maybe try to install appnope from pip, as python 3.6 is starting to be old, and might not be supported on conda on more recent macOS versions.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for your kinda help. In fact, I did `conda list | grep appnope` and I got  `appnope                   0.1.2` which seems to be the most recent version of appnope. I could also import it in python shell. 
I found a discussion on github around this! Looks like the problem, as you mention, is about python 3.6, conda and macOS 11.5! 
I post what I did as an answer for the reference of other peoplE!

Answer (score 2):

As the first answer says, the problem looks like to stem from python 3.6, conda and macOS 11.5! I followed this [post](https://github.com/minrk/appnope/issues/12) and it worked for me.

"disable appnope in the IPython kernel by setting:

```
# ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py
c.Kernel._darwin_app_nap = False
```

Comment: Great ! As IPython .py files are executed, you could even test for python version and/or os version to change the value of this dynamically.